# Error: Can't Assign to Function Call

Tags: python, string, variables, integer, calculator

I am trying to make a simple calculator for addition, and am experiencing a problem.

```
print('welcome to calculator')      # Print opening message
print(' ')  #Spacer
int(sum1) = input('number') # Get input for first number, this variable later becomes the sum : ERROR: Can't assign to function call
int(add1) = input('number') # Get input for second number : Assumed error for this line as well
sum1 = sum1 + add1      # Add the variables together to get the sum
print(str(sum1))    # Change the sum to a string and print it
loop = 1    # Set loop to True
while loop == 1:    # Continue the program until user inputs add1 as '0'
    int(add1) = input('number')     # Get value for add1
    if add1 == 0:   # Stop the program when add1 is equal to 0
        loop = 0    # Set loop to false
        break
    sum1 = sum1 + add1  # Add the variables together to get the new sum
    print(str(sum1))    # Change the sum to a string and print it
print('done!')  # Print ending message
```

The error here is on the third line (And I assume the fourth would have the error too). I originally just had

```
sum1 = input('number')
```

but the variable sum1 was being treated as a string, so in line 5 when the variables sum1 and add1 were to be added, it would add the strings to the ends of each other. (Example: 15 + 10 = 1510)

Am I doing something wrong when I'm converting the variable to an integer, or is this the wrong way to get past the issue?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3? If it's python 2, you should be using `raw_input()` rather than `input()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to assign to the result of an `int()` function call:

```
int(sum1) = input('number')
```

Everything on the left-hand side of the `=` sign should be a target to store the result produced by the right-hand side, and you are asking Python to store something in `int(sum1)`.

If you wanted to *convert* the result of the `input()` call to an integer, you'll need to apply it to the return value of the `input()` call, not the variable in which you are storing that result:

```
sum1 = int(input('number'))
```

The same applies to both `add1` cases in your code; use:

```
add1 = int(input('number'))
```

Now the right-hand side expression produces an integer result, to be stored in `sum1` and `add1` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `int(sum1) = input('number')` is invalid and should be `sum1 = int(input('number'))`
in the second case you're casting the input into an `int` - which is what you want. In the first case you're trying to cast a function - what `Python` is complaining about.

Also this should be changed everywhere in your code !

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert it to integer, this is the correct way for that;

```
x = int(input("something"))
```