# 'Must be a str, not int' when trying to increment a integer

Tags: python-3.x

So for quite a few hours, i've been stuck in a problem I can't seem to wrap my head around, here is the python code:

```
lines = User3^1
dsplit = lines.split('^')
value = dsplit[1][:1]
value += 1
```

Essentially, what's going on here is I take a string and split it then grab the starting number and place it onto a integer called value then increment it by one to get the job done, the problem is that Python throws an error when trying to increment of:

```
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

I've researched this on Google alot and none of the answers that come up match my problem, what i've done so far is I tried to convert into an Integer by doing:

```
int(value) += 1
```

but it gives me an error message when I try to run of 'Can't assign to function call'

I am completely puzzled, could someone please help me figure this out?
Thank you!

Comment: When you split a string it’s still a string. You have to convert it into an int if you want it to be one

Comment: This is what i've been trying to do for the past 3 hours, but can't get around it for reasons mentioned in post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Error: Can't Assign to Function Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198355/error-cant-assign-to-function-call)
first comment explains why u got error 'Can't Assign to Function Call'

```
lines = 'User3^1'
dsplit = lines.split('^')
value = int(dsplit[1][:1])
value += 1 #output 2
```

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I was missing something so obvious, I was trying to convert value itself to an integer, but not the value I was inputting to it (the split string)